# Debian: Blank screen with running process?

Tags: debian, openvpn

In Debian settings, I have it set to go to a blank screen (lock the screen) after 5 minutes. This normally works fine. However, when I am connected to my VPN via openvpn, my screen never locks. I assume this is because openvpn is constantly running (in my Terminal window it is "frozen" on the line "Initialization Sequence Completed", but it still connects to the VPN fine).

Is there a way to "force" the blank screen, even if a process is running in the background like this?

Edit: I call my VPN using openvpn. Essentially, this is `openvpn 'vpn-config.ovpn'`. This connects, but then hangs at "Initialization Sequence Completed" - but I'm connected to the VPN at this point, so I leave it "running" in the Terminal window.

Comment: Please add to the question how you call your VPN.

Comment: This isn't normal. Whatever you're running in a terminal (or elsewhere) should not impact your idle time and prevent the screen from locking. Something somewhere is doing something else (sorry, I can't be more precise).

Comment: Use `vlock` to lock your screen properly.

Comment: concur, this isn't normal, I use debian + openvpn command line, and i never have issue with screenlock. (am using xfce+xscreensaver, perhaps your issue is a quirk with the dm?), Perhaps a solution for you is to use keyboard shortcut to lock screen? I've setup my laptop to auto lock when a security device is removed.